# Using the For statement in python 3x

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a for statement to bind each character of the lower-case alphabet to the name "c" (no need to write a loop body). I understand that they are used when you want to repeat a loop but I'm just blanking on this question because I'm not seeing how they go together, can someone help a nooby out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
for character in ascii_lowercase:
    c = character
```